# Ettercap error, networking

Tags: kali-linux

Ettercap says to not run as host for are poisoning on github,

so how is it suppose to be ran on my network or outside of network looking in... I've tried the echo 1 forward option , but every time I send a arp on my network it stops all activity on all devices ... is there a critical piece  of information I'm missing...or is my Cisco E4200 router blocking the arp replies ?

Anyone have any insight, it'd be great

Answer (score 0):

Ettercap not work very well, you have to try MITMF. It's the best, have a lot of modules like JavaScript injection, key-logger, portal-captive, etc.